# Calculate factor group $(\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z})/\langle(1,1,1)\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

My instructor's said at the lecture that you basically set one of the dimensions to $0$ and hence you get $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$.  Again, is there a better way to think about this problem and approach it?  I am only a novice abstract algebra student and his instructions are way too chaotic here.

Comment: You've been asking quite a few similar questions. Honestly, this suggests a more fundamental lack of understanding of the concepts. Perhaps you should ask a single question regarding the nature of how to handle these problems.

I don't mean this in a negative way, as someone who has tutored for over a decade, I think it's important to get at the core of the confusion.

Comment: I've tried before but I haven't gotten very satisfactory answers.  Perhaps you can suggest some way that I can understand this.

Comment: @camox, you may benefit from this: http://math.berkeley.edu/~williams/113/Math113quotients.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Your instructor's intuition is correct, but we can formalize this by writing down an explicit isomorphism $\tilde{\Phi}: \mathbb{Z}^3 / \langle(1, 1, 1)\rangle \to \mathbb{Z}^2$.

First, given an element $(a, b, c) \in \mathbb{Z}^3$, it is equivalent to exactly one element of the form $(x, y, 0)$, namely
$$(a, b, c) + (-c) \cdot (1, 1, 1) = (a - c, b - c, 0),$$ and so each coset contains exactly one element of that form.

Now, the set of elements of the form $(x, y, 0)$ obviously form a group under addition isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$, via the map $(x, y, 0) \mapsto (x, y)$, which suggests we consider the homomorphism $\Phi: \mathbb{Z}^3 \to \mathbb{Z}^2$ defined by
$$\Phi: (a, b, c) \mapsto (a - c, b - c).$$
By construction, $\Phi$ is constant on the cosets, so it factors to a map $\tilde{\Phi}: \mathbb{Z}^3 / \langle(1, 1, 1)\rangle \to \mathbb{Z}^2$. This map is surjective because $\Phi$ is, and it is injective because of our observation that each coset contains exactly one element of the form $(x, y, 0)$, so it is an isomorphism. (Of course, we can also check these latter two claims directly.)